# Kinematics - moving body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction, free-body-diagram

If I have an inclined plane, which has acceleration $\alpha$, will a block placed on the inclined plane slip back with the same acceleration? (considering that the surface is frictionless)

Comment: So far, the question is underspecified. Is the plane accelerated by an outside force or is it moving freely in reaction to the weight of the block?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No,

Long answer: let's say your plane is moving to the right. If the plane were purely horizontal (like a cube) and friction less, the block placed on top won't even move (there is no force on it except gravity and the normal force from the block underneath it). 
Now lets look at an inclined plane. The block placed on top again has only two forces acting on it, gravity (straight down), and the normal force which no longer acts straight up. Instead it acts at an angle with the incline plane.

As a general problem solving strategy, draw free body diagrams for every problem like this!